# shell_exec & clamav

Tags: php

When i call this:

```
exec("clamscan --no-summary file.php", $out, $int);
```

with good parameters, the script doesn't finish. The file is too small and in console its command duration is 2 seconds.

If I put incorrect parameter the script finished and return correct error code.

With `shell_exec` it does the same.

Comment: Does clamscan happen to expect keyboard input at some point?

Comment: Running it from console should not press anything

Comment: Have you tried popen? Or system?

Comment: Yes it does the same with popen with 'r' option. 
The program works, only fails with the correct parameters. Any limitation php? program fail? Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean exactly with correct/incorrect parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Whith incorrect parameters it works fine, return code 40.

Whith correct parameters it not works, the script never finish and it not return code.

When i execute ps -A are many clamscan instances.